# Display select combo with Model driven template with Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have a component using ReactiveForms that is using :

```
    <form [formGroup]="generalDataForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <select name="grade_id" id="grade_id" class="form-control" formControlName="grade_id">
          <option *ngFor="let grade of grades" [ngValue]="grade.id [selected]="grade.id === user.grade_id">
{{ grade.text | translate }} {{ user.grade_id }} {{ user.grade_id === grade.id }}
           </option>
     </select>
      <div align="right">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

In mock_grades.ts, I have:

```
export const GRADES: Grade[] = [
  {
    'id': 0,
    'text': 'add_cat.no_grade_restriction',
    'order': 0,
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'text': '7 Kyu',
    'order': 1,
  },       etc...
```

And in my component, I have:

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  generalDataForm: FormGroup;
  public type = 'component';
  grades = GRADES;
  ...
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.generalDataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: [this.user.name, Validators.required],
    firstname: [''],
    lastname: [''],
    grade_id: [''],
    country_id: ['']
  }
  }
  }
```

I can have the list of value OK, but I can't select the selected item.

It is weird, because I print the condition result on every item, and it is true when it should be selected, but it doesn't select item...

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

should be `GRADES` in `ngFor`

```
*ngFor="let grade of GRADES"
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfruze?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: sorry, my mistake, in component, I have grades = GRADES; and GRADES is defined as const and exported in his own file, I will update the question

Comment: Yes, I can do it without reactive forms, but with reactive forms, it seems that ngValue is not doing the trick anymore

Comment: add `generalDataForm = new FormControl();` to component

Comment: I updated the question, I had already it defined to :  this.generalDataForm = this.formBuilder.group({all validation...])

Comment: I am doing a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u11pdk but I can't make it work :(

Comment: add `user = {'grade_id': 0}` and import `ReactiveFormsModule` in the module

Comment: ok, now demo is working, well, failing, but this is the point

Comment: what are u trying to do exactly ?